# Hexadecimal number sequence checker in Linux?

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing, ksh, arithmetic

I have a list of hexadecimal number. I would like to check whether they are in sequence or not. That is, they should be consecutive numbers, in increasing order. In other words, there should be an increment of 1 from each line to the next.

Sample list of hexadecimal numbers:

```
85AF
85B0
85B1
85B2
85B3
85B4
85B5
85B6
85B7
85B8
85B9
85BA
85BB
85BC
85BD
85BE
85BF
85C0
```

In reality I would have more than 500 numbers to check through.

Desired output:

```
All numbers are in sequence
     (or)
Numbers are not in sequence.
```

This is on Solaris, with ksh.

Answer (score 2):

Awk could do this easily if the output was in decimal, but it can't parse hexadecimal numbers (at least standard awk can't, some versions such as GNU awk can). You can use `bc` to do the conversion. This works on all POSIX systems.

```
{ echo "ibase=16"; cat input.txt; } | bc |
awk 'NR==1 {origin = $0-1}
     $0!=origin+NR {print "Out-of-sequence number at line", NR; exit(1)}' >&2
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in another answer, it would be nice to do this in awk, but ancient awk (the one probably available in Solaris) doesn't understand hex numbers.

A fast solution is to use `wc -l` and some ksh math:

```
#! /bin/ksh

first="0x$(head -n1 infile)"
last="0x$(tail -n1 infile)"
lines=$(wc -l <infile)

if [[ "$(( last - first + 1 - lines ))" -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "All numbers are in sequence."
else
    echo "Numbers are not in sequence."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

```
while read x; do echo $((16#$x)); done <yourfile | awk 's && $1!=s+1{exit(1)}{s=$1}'
```

This shell command will produce an exit status of 1 (on fail) and 0 (on success). This command can be used e.g. in an if-clause like the following to produce the desired output:

```
if  while read x; do echo $((16#$x)); done < yourfile | awk 's && $1!=s+1{exit(1)}{s=$1}'
then echo All numbers are in sequence
else echo Numbers are not in sequence
fi
```

(Note that you have you substitute the name "yourfile" by the file name that contains your hex number sequence.)

You can also omit the shell loop and use GNU `awk`'s option `-n` to process the hex numbers directly:

```
if  sed 's/^/0x/' <yourfile | awk -n 's && $1+0!=s+1{exit(1)}{s=$1+0}'
then echo All numbers are in sequence
else echo Numbers are not in sequence.
fi
```

Note: sed is used here to create the syntactically expected format for the hex numbers (with leading `0x`).

Comment: this method seems to be nice. But i can not put it in a script. awk is bailing out with a syntax error. Can you provide me the .KSH file.

Comment: Which of the two versions are you trying? And are you working on solaris? - In the latter case see whether you have a GNU `awk` installed. Or else try the first version with `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` (instead of the default `awk`). - WRT the requested "`ksh` file"; you would just copy/paste the posted code in a file `testhexseq` (don't forget to adjust the name of the hex source file), and call it as `ksh testhexseq`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like strict sequence it can be easy done by produce etalon sequence and compare it with file

```
[ $(comm --nocheck-order -3 \
     <(sed '/\S/!d' file) \
     <(printf "%X\n" \
          $(seq $((16#$(sed '/./!d;q' file))) \
                $((16#$(tac file|sed '/./!d;q')))))) ] &&
echo 'Numbers are not in sequence' ||
echo 'All numbers are in sequence'
```

Just to check if all numbers are hexadecimal:

```
sed '/^[[:xdigit:] ]*$/!{
        s/.*/Numbers are not in sequence: &/
        q
                        }
     $! d
     s/.*/All numbers are in sequence/' hexadecimal_number.list
```

- `/^[[:xdigit:] ]*$/` check if in line there are hexadecimal symbols and space only (or nothing - empty line)
- `!` reverse match, so execute commands in `{}` just if there some other symbols than described above
- `s/.*/.../;q` `s`ubstitute all line by `Numbers are not in sequence` than `q`uit script with printing line
- `$! d` if script didn't execute previous (pattern match) and if line is not last `d`elete it it start with next line
- `s/.*/.../` if script reach last line (so all lines match pattern) `s`ubstitute last line by `All numbers are in sequence` an print it

Comment: should i put this in a script and run it or its a single line command? i am newbie, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @ayrton_senna; Typically longer commands are put in a file (say `yourscript`) and executed by calling the file with a shell (e.g. `bash yourscript`). - But in this case I don't see that this code works - it certainly doesn't work when I tried - nor do I see how it would do the desired task. (Costas may want to explain it.)

Comment: @ayrton_senna Up to you. It can be used in all variants.

Comment: @Janis I have tested - it work

Comment: @Costas; If I remove one of the lines in the data file, or add a data element AAAA - in both cases disturbing the order -, I still get a positive result, even though it shouldn't. - Are you sure you tested those cases?

Comment: @Janis `AAAA` is hexadecimal ;)

Comment: @Costas; yes, but not **in sequence**.

Comment: @Costas i can not do scripting. i am new to linux & using korn shell. can you provide me a 1 line command that i can execute and check. or can you provide me the .ksh file which i can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` with the option `-c` to check if the input data is sorted:

> -c
>
> Check that the single input file is ordered as specified by the arguments and
>   the collating sequence of the current locale. Output
>   shall not be sent to  standard output. The exit code shall indicate
>   whether or not disorder was  detected or an error occurred. If
>   disorder (or, with -u, a duplicate key) is  detected, a warning
>   message shall be sent to standard error indicating where  the disorder
>   or duplicate key was found.

So a simple

```
LC_ALL=C \
sort -c data 2> /dev/null \
&& echo All numbers are in sequence \
|| echo Numbers are not in sequence
```

would do.

Comment: Do not work with trailing empty lines. Just remove it and use `<(sed '/\S/!d' data)` instead `data`

Comment: @Costas OP doesn't say anything about trailing lines.

Comment: This doesn't check that the increment is 1 (as clarified in a comment prior to your answer).

Comment: This wasn't a requirement in OP before your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input file *hexlist.txt*, this works in `ksh` and `bash`.  It uses the [`numinterval`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) util.  If `numinterval` isn't available, uncomment the faker function:

```
# fake `numinterval` function
# numinterval() { printf '%s %s r - p\n' $(sed '1!{$!p}') | dc ; }

n=; eval printf '%s\\n' $(printf '$((16#%s\n)) ' $(<hexlist.txt)) | 
numinterval | grep -qw 1 || n=not ; echo All numbers are $n in sequence
```